# Who is responsible for the process with API requests in Domain Layer of DDD(Domain Driven Design)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm a beginner in DDD.

<s>I have no idea who is responsible for the process with API request.</s>
I have no idea who is responsible for the function depending indirectly on Infrastructure Layer.
Such as the function with Web API request.

For example I'm creating online shopping system and the system supports order cancel.

I think I have 2 class candidates in domain layer to implement order cancellation function.
  A: Domain Service
  B: Domain Object

But I can't judge which is better.

I worry that Design "A" is too procedural and it looks anemic.
I also worry that Design "B" makes domain object too knowledgeable and dependent. (Because I think object should be as simple as possible)

**Design Candidate A**

```
// Simple but anemic
class Order {
    id: number;
    date: Date;
    state: OrderState;

    constructor(
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }
}

// Procedural
class OrderService {
    private readonly orderRepository: OrderRepository;

    constructor(
        orderRepository: OrderRepository
    ) {
        ...
    }

    cancel(orderId: number): void {
        orderRepository.update(orderId, { state: OrderSate.Cancelled });
    }
}
```

**Design Candidate B**

```
// knowledgeable and dependent
class Order {
    id: number;
    date: Date;
    state: OrderState;

    private readonly orderRepository: OrderRepository;

    constructor(
        orderRepository: OrderRepository,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }

    cancel(): void {
        orderRepository.update(this.id, { state: OrderSate.Cancelled });
    }
}
```

[The model I thought](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSnb4.png)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm a beginner in DDD. I have no idea who is responsible for the process with API request.

The business logic belongs in the domain model, the orchestration belongs in the application.

Thus, the logic in your *application* would normally look something like...

```
Order order = orderRepository.get(orderId);
order.cancel();
```

The Order model is responsible for knowing how to manipulate its own in-memory data structure when `Order::cancel` is invoked.  The OrderRepository is responsible for persistence.  The application drives the invocation of the other two elements.

Part of the confusion is that the concept "service" is overloaded.  In DDD, "domain service" refers to a pattern that is part of the domain model (just like value objects and entities are domain model patterns).

**Update 20190120**

> But who updates the database in the server? Your code seems that database in server has't been updated yet if order.cancel() update only own memory. This is my thinking.

That's a really important question, isn't it? :)

When Eric Evans first described the repository pattern in his book, he deliberately choose a repository pattern with collection semantics and suggested that transaction management should be an *application* concern.

In pseudo code:

```
beginTransaction();
Order order = orderRepository.get(orderId);
order.cancel();
commitTransaction();
```

The notion being that the underlying *mapper* can review the repository and discover which entities are "dirty", and thereby generate the appropriate calls to your persistent store.

More recently, you are more likely to see repositories with *storage*, rather than collection, semantics

```
beginTransaction();
Order order = orderRepository.get(orderId);
order.cancel();
orderRepository.save(order);
commitTransaction();
```

The basic mechanics are the same, but we've eliminated some of the magic of how the changes are shared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
> The Order model is responsible for knowing how to manipulate its own in-memory
Yes, I think so too. But who updates the database in the server?
Your code seems that database in server has't been updated yet if order.cancel() update only own memory.
This is my thinking.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSnb4.png

Comment: I see. In other words, no one in domain layer is responsible for the server request, but application layer is responsible for it, isn't it?

Comment: Learnt a lot. A highlight to this answer: "When Eric Evans first described the repository pattern in his book, he deliberately choose a repository pattern with collection semantics and suggested that transaction management should be an application concern."

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives to these options. One is to do away with the repository thing, and have the model define the behavior:

```java
public interface Order {
    void cancel();
}
```

And then implement the behavior with the help of a specific technology:

```java
public final class SqlOrder implements Order {
    ...
    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        connection.execute("update order...");
    }
}
```

Depending on your use-cases this might result in following benefits: Not anemic, gets rid of potentially unnecessary indirection (the repository), uses domain language and not CRUD technicalities, is more maintainable, easily testable because the order is just an interface now, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Do you mean the followings? 1. I should define only interface as Domain Object and implement it in Infrastructure Layer as far as possible. 2. The implementation of Domain Object is allowed to contain not only data object but also functional object. I feel strange about 2, because I have been told that "The data or entity class should contain only data object. For example, student.graduate() should be student.graduate(school)". Perhaps my way of thinknig may be old.

Comment: Data-only objects are certainly a popular approach, but it is not the only one. I prefer to move along the business language (the ubiquitous language) as the Blue Book suggests. This means that any *syntactical* construct should be a valid *business* functionality (as far as possible). To turn it around: I shouldn't be able to write code (a sequence of calls for example) that doesn't make sense in business context. Functional developers would say: If it compiles, it works.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, I would not do this for *all* "business objects". For some of them it makes sense, for others less so. I would always decide what I use based on the functionality it needs to provide.

Comment: Thank you! I now have a deeper understanding.